# Can't get PHP to return a value

Tags: php, function, return-value

I know that this is an insanely basic question, but I'm new to PHP and am trying to write some simple 'getter' functions that are stored in a separate file.

I keep getting this error, and I can't figure out why.

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   D:\Hosting\xxxxxxx\html\mysite\scripts\convert_ids.php on line 15

Here is the script from the calling function:

```
include 'scripts/convert_ids.php';        
$group = getGroup(2);
echo $group;
```

And this is the getter function:

**convert_ids.php**

```
<?php

    include('connection.php');

    function getGroup($id) {

        $sql = "SELECT group FROM Groups WHERE id=$id";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$result) {
            return -1;
        }

        $row = $mysql_fetch_array($result);    //<--this is line 15
        return $row['group'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with `$mysql_fetch_array`. It should be `mysql_fetch_array`. Please refrain from using these functions as they are deprecated. You can use mysqli/PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row = $mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Should be

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Haha no problem, I've asked dumber questions

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` for `$row['group']`

`mysql_fetch_array` you will need to use `$row[0]`

Also don't put a `$` in front of `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: Actually, `mysql_fetch_array` will return both numeric and associative arrays by default.